# A generic career advise question

Tags: india, careers, first-job

It is an generic question seeking for an career advise. Please skip this if you aren't interested in answering this. Thank you.

HI, I recently attended an interview in an MNC company. Interview went pretty well and I am confident that I will get the job. But they want me to work in the 'Software Maintenance' of the application rather than giving an developer designation. I always wanted to be an developer. I am fresher and I am not sure whether to join in the company or not. By the way they wanted me to sign a 2 years of bond plus handover them a 2 Lakh security check. Salary they are offering is 20k per month.

Will joining in the software maintenance department help to in any way to grow as of an product is a developer or not?

Any suggestions will be really helpful for me.
Any advice would mean a lot.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Career advice is off topic,  voting to close.

Comment: Don't know about India, but in Western countries, no one would hand his company a security check worth ten months of salary.

Comment: The Indian system of employment seems really really evil, the more and more I read about it...

Answer (score 6):

Maintenance often includes developing code to fix bugs, though it would not include adding new functionality.

Maintaining code can be an excellent way to learn how the existing code works and what the company's design practices and toolset are, so newcomers are often asked to start as maintainers.

Code, like most products, spends most of its life in maintenance mode.  Maintenance isn't always as satisfying as creating something entirely new, but it is equally important; sometimes more so. And in a good organization there isn't a hard division between maintenance and development, and it should be possible to move between the two later.

So that's the question I would ask, if I were you: Will there be opportunities later to work on new development. If sp, starting in maintenance may be a very reasonable approach.

Comment: 2nd paragraph hits the spot very well

Comment: Maintenance can include developing new features, as well. It just depends on how the company defines those roles. Either way, you're right. A "software maintenance" job is still a developer and is a great place for a new developer to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. HR said there might be an opportunity to shift but he seems to be unsure about it.